Lexicographic/dictionary order topology and a set
I have been doing an exercise in which I was requested to find the interior of the set $A = [0,1/2] \times [0,1)$, viewed as a subset of the space $X = [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and the lexicographic order topology. I wanted to know if my answer is right:

$$\operatorname{Int}(A) = [0,1/2] \times (0,1)$$. This is because the lexicographic order/dictionary order topology in $X$ can be viewed as the product topology of discrete and usual order ones in the set, so every open set has the form $\{a \} \times (b,c), a,b,c\in [0,1], b < c$ (or is the union of arbitrarily times of these). So, for each number in the first component $x$, one can take $\{x \}$ to cover the first coordinate, and for each $y \in (0,1)$, there is an open interval that contains $y$ and is in $(0,1)$. This does not happen for the points $y = 0, y = 1$, so they are excluded, and how is it that I reached this conclusion?

What I'm not sure about is that in the answer to the exercise, it says that $\operatorname{Int}(A) = [0,1/2] \times(0,1) \cup \{(0,0) \}$. The reason they say it is like this is that you can cover the point with a semi-open interval. For the first coordinate there is not any problem since you can "cover" with $\{0\}$, but, can you use a semi-open interval for the second coordinate? In my notes I have that in lexicographic order topology, the interval $((a,b)(a,d)) = \{a \} \times (b,d)$ forms a basis. Maybe the exercise uses a slightly different definition or maybe is because the total set is bounded, I don't know.

I think the issue is related to the problem of defining "the first element" of an open set like (0,1).  Although the real line is well ordered, when dealing with closed intervals this fundamentally changes the topology of the space.  Normally in topology we deal with open sets, but you are using the closed interval [0,1/2].  It seems to me that whereas the rest of the topology is defined in terms of open sets, the point 0 needs to be treated in a special way.  (this is my guess based on my intuition and have not heard of some of these terms before such as "lexographic order topology")

In the answer I'm given it says indeed that ${ (0,0)}$ is the minimum point of the set given this order.

The solution is right.

In my notes I have that in lexicographic order topology, the interval $((a,b)(a,d)) = \{a \} \times (b,d)$ form a basis.

That is true for $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. But here we are looking at $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, so, for $0<\epsilon\leq 1$, the set $\{0\}\times[0,\epsilon)$ is open in $X$, because it is the set of all elements of $X$ that are $<(0,\epsilon)$, i.e. it is an open interval with respect to $X$ (but obviously not with respect to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$).
Your proof that $(x,0)$ is not an interior point for $x>0$ is clearly not correct, since you didn't distinguish between $x>0$ and $x=0$. Maybe you can provide a better one yourself, once you've understood the problem with $(0,0)$.

What may shed some light on this is to look at the general definition of the order topology at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology . The topology is defined by a subbase consisting of rays in either direction: ${x: x < a}$ and ${x: x > a}$, where $a$ varies over the elements of the set.  That's why the  $< (0,\epsilon)$ argument above works, it is simply using an open set as defined in the subbase.
